# Multiple calls extracting items from shared Queue in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

If there's a queue of work todo in a table that is going to be periodically polled by a number of different worker clients...what's the best way to prevent each worker from getting the same item to work on?

Say a table like:   ItemId, LastAttemptDateTime, AttemptCount, and various item details.

Given an index on LastAttemptDateTime and sorted in ascending order and various clients are querying the table to grab an item to be worked on.

I use a stored procedure in MS SQL to do this...something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNextQueueItem AS

SET NOCOUNT ON 

DECLARE @ItemId INT

UPDATE myqueue SET @ItemId=ItemId, AttemptCount=AttemptCount+1, LastAttemptDateTime=GetDate() 
WHERE ItemId=(SELECT TOP 1 ItemId 
FROM myqueue 
ORDER BY LastAttemptDateTime ASC)

SELECT ItemId, AttemptCount, and various item detail fields 
FROM myqueue 
WHERE ItemId = @ItemId
```

I'm fairly new to PostgreSQL and was wondering if there's alternate approaches available. (The TOP 1 will change to LIMIT 1.)

Comment: Check out this post: http://johtopg.blogspot.com/2010/12/queues-in-sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL equivalent could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_next_queue_item()
  RETURNS SETOF myqueue AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    UPDATE myqueue
    SET    attempt_count = attempt_count + 1
          ,last_attempt_ts = now()
    WHERE  item_id = (
        SELECT item_id
        FROM   myqueue 
        ORDER  BY last_attempt_ts
        LIMIT  1
        )
    RETURNING myqueue.*;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

#### Major points

- You only need **1 statement** to do it all. `UPDATE` can return the updated row in the same command with the `RETURNING` clause.
  <sub>State of the row is post-update. There is ways to get the pre-update state if needed.</sub>
- No need for any variables.
- I changed all identifiers to lower case, which is the cleanest style in PostgreSQL.
- I renamed your column `LastAttemptDateTime` to `last_attempt_ts`
  ts .. for "timestamp", because that's the name of the timestamp / datetime type in Postgres.
- As you mentioned yourself, `LIMIT 1` instead of `TOP 1`.
- I use `RETURNS SETOF myqueue` as return type.
  <sup>`myqueue` is the associated row-type of the table `myqueue` - for every table or view a row-type of the same name is automatically created in PostgreSQL.</sup>
  This declaration allows for multiple rows to be returned, but `LIMIT 1` guarantees that it will only ever be one.
- This return type allows for [RETURN QUERY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) to return the resulting row directly without any intermediate step. Fast, clean.

Actually, you don't *need* a plpgsql function at all. You can do it with a **simple SQL statement**:

```
UPDATE myqueue
SET    attempt_count = attempt_count + 1
      ,last_attempt_ts = now()
WHERE  item_id = (
    SELECT item_id
    FROM   myqueue 
    ORDER  BY last_attempt_ts
    LIMIT  1
    )
RETURNING myqueue.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PostgreSQL has sequences separate to identity columns incremented with them that can be used for other things, one nice way to do have a sequence used to set an id on the table, and another for getting the item:

1. Look at the `currval` of the sequence, if it's higher than or equal to the `max` id of the table, there's no items waiting.
2. Obtain `nextval`. If there is no item with a matching id then loop back to 1 (this can happen if an insert to the table failed).
3. Obtain the row with the matching id.

This isn't the only way to skin this cat (and not the way I've used with other databases), but has the advantage of being light on writes to the database (altering only the sequence, not the table.